# How to only show chat in mIRC window

Tags: irc, mirc

Is there any way to only show what is said on the window without showing everytime someone logs in or out (filling up the screen)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click (or left click, i'm running mIRC in wine and right click does nothing for me) on the left icon in your chat window title bar to bring up a menu.  Select events, and you can then choose which events to display in that particular window.

Alternatively, you can go to Tools->Options->IRC.  From there you can set these same event options as default.